# count function in sql

Tags: java, sql

```
account_id    current_balance  opening_date
1             100              2012-03-01
2             100              2012-4-01 
3             100              2013-03-1
```

now when I am running query in sql work bench it's fine

```
select count(acc.account_id) 
from daily_account acc 
where acc.opening_date < '2013-03-01'
```

but when I am running this in NetBeans it is not giving proper output.

```
select count(acc.account_id) 
from daily_account acc 
where acc.opening_date < '"+ new Date((Integer.parseInt(FromYearComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString())-1900),FromMonthComboBox.getSelectedIndex(),Integer.parseInt(FromDateComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString()))).toString()
```

can any one help me why is this happening?

Edit :

```
rs = st.executeQuery("select count(acc.account_id) from daily_account
acc where  acc.opening_date < '"+ new
Date((Integer.parseInt(FromYearComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString())-1900),FromMonthComboBox.getSelectedIndex(),(Integer.parseInt(FromDateComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString()))).toString()+"';");

rs.next();

tabledata[0][2]=rs.getString(1);
```

> Edit ::
>    It is giving me wrong answer ...it is counting all the account id...

Comment: You'll have to show the code you're using in Netbeans that generates that query text.

Comment: I would avoid java code in sql. First get it into a variable and see the value you are getting is valid or not.

Comment: it is giving me proper output on place of date

Comment: Could you post the resulting query string? And you should really think about using prepared statements if you don't want to run into trouble later.

Comment: If you are getting proper value, you might have wrong syntax or something, why not simplify by having value of date in variable?

Comment: use preparedStatements instead of simple statement.

Comment: Ashish, you have big mess over there, don't worry about having an extra variable, get date value to variable and then test it.

Comment: Another point is why not create a function in database and call the function from Java? By doing that sql code would remain in database. Pass parameters to function using preparedStatement.

Comment: What is the output it is giving and what are you expecting? Also, your code is unreadable, too many nested calls. Break things down and check that the values makes sense at each step. Whoever maintains this after you will thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an extra closing braces `)` in the end i.e `toString())))`. It should be one less e.g.

> select count(acc.account_id) from daily_account acc where acc.opening_date < '"+ new Date((Integer.parseInt(FromYearComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString())-1900),FromMonthComboBox.getSelectedIndex(),Integer.parseInt(FromDateComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString())).toString()+"'";

**One note** This is really making your query string complex to maintain. Try constructing the date string before hand and then append in the query.

**Another Note:** `Date` constructor with arguments is deprecated, and it also seems that you really don't need the date but string. In that case, why don't you write something simple as :

```
 String dateStr = 
      String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(
                              FromYearComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString())-1900)
  + FromMonthComboBox.getSelectedIndex()
  +FromDateComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();

String queryStr = "select count(acc.account_id) from daily_account acc "+
                  " where acc.opening_date < '"+ dateStr +"'";
```

Comment: sorry for that ...but that is correct and thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Ashishsingh: When I try looking at string in eclipse, it show one extra brace. Also please check the updated answer. I added another section.

Comment: @Ashishsingh Can you log/sysout `queryStr` and see what query string is getting formed? Also, why are you substracting 1900 from the year?

Comment: i got my answer i have not imported the SQl Date Class of Java

Comment: Good you got it.. but looking at your sql example, its really impossible to know what you were trying to achieve and how the sql date fixes your issue.

Comment: @Ashishsingh: Looks like you are still using your old pattern of getting the date string :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19351/discussion-between-yogendra-singh-and-ashishsingh)

Comment: @Ashishsingh All I am trying to say that, if you need string in the end to use in the query then why you are converting `fragments -> String -> Date -> String`. Aren't you done after first step i.e. `fragments -> String`? If you want the date string in some different format then use `DateFormat/SimpleDateFormat` class, where you have better control of formatting/parsing.